# How to make sure all students are allocated to a branch when one is freed?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database of students in college. My job is to perform Branch Up-gradation. So, say, my table rows in the student table are:

```
id, Name, Old_Branch, New_Branch
```

And, the rows of the college table are:

```
id, Branch, Vacancies
```

Now, the objective is for each student, check if there are any vacancies in his new branch. If there are, change the student's branch in the old table, and decrease the vacancies of the new branch and increase the vacancies of the old branch in the college table.

**Now, the problem is**:

Suppose my college table was:

```
id    Branch    Vacancies
 1       abc            0
 2       def            1
```

And, my student table was:

```
id    Name   Old_Branch    New_Branch
 1    Mike          def           abc
 2   Ralph          abc           def
```

As you can see, in the first iteration, Mike is not given abc, even though in the next iteration, 1 spot in abc gets freed, since Ralph moves from abc to def, hence in the college table, value of abc becomes 1.

So, my question is what logic do I use so that I can ensure that each student gets up-gradation keeping in mind all the changes that could later free spots that were not free earlier.

Comment: By "old", you mean previous? Do you have some date-related logic for leaving/entering a branch? Maybe you should be better off with a one-to-many (one student to many branches) relationship, and take into account only the latest entry (the most recent).

Comment: No, no, only previous. No date involved...

Comment: So how many previous do you need to store? Only one per student? Strange way to handle data...

Comment: I don't think you are understanding the question. See, there are only 2 tables, one that handles student data, and another that handles college data. Both are constantly updated, when the loop is running. It is really quite simple.

Comment: Which loop? Your question is missing the loop. "First iteration" and "next iteration" means nothing to me, sorry. Also, you should referring branches ID's in your student table, not strings. What does "constantly" mean? Your process is looping 24 hours a day, every second?

Comment: I left it out on purpose, because it could be any loop, a for, or a while, which simply iterates over all rows in the table. My question is simply how many times this loop must run, and how to add an ending condition.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds rude, I don't mean it that way, but... How much MySQL, or RDBM experience do you have? I don't see the need for a loop whatsoever in your case.

Comment: Well, I have about a year of experience, but if you have a nice solution, I would request you to please post it.

Comment: I would suggest to rephrase your question. Some things are not clear. Are students booking for a branch? What I mean is : if there is 0 vacancies for branch "abc", you need to somehow store all students requests for "abc", to fulfill them one by one, if vacancies for "abc" become gradually available?

Comment: Yes, what you say is correct, that is what is happening. The issue is if a vacancy opens up after a while, then the earlier students won't get the vacancy, and will miss it. So, every time a vacancy opens up, I have to iterate over all students. I just need to know when to stop these iterations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57217/discussion-between-bonatoc-and-thescarecrow).